# Use of derived class' typedefs in base

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I want the derived class to be a descendant of a template class. That class depends on descendant's members.
In short I want this code to compile:

```
struct IBootParams
{
    virtual bool GetImmediate() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct TBootBootParams
{
    typename T::TransType transferType;

    typename T::UseAbort_ useAbort;

    bool GetImmediate()
    {
        if ( transferType == T::e1 )
        {
            return useAbort.someFlag;
        }

        return false;
    }

};

struct BootBootParams : public TBootBootParams<BootBootParams> 
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=0,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        char        someMember;             
        int         otherMember;        
    } useAbort;

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

struct BootAltBootParams : public TBootBootParams<BootAltBootParams> 
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        long long       someMember;             
        long long       otherMember;        
    } useAbort;

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BootBootParams bp;
    BootAltBootParams bpa;

    bool f = bp.GetImmediate();
    f = bpa.GetImmediate();
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare IBootParams?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it this way. When the compiler instantiates `TBootBootParams<BootBootParams>` it has not yet completely read the whole definition of BootBootParams so you can't access its members from inside the definition of TBootBootParams (member functions of TBootBootParams are an exception because they are instantiated later).

The usual solution is to have a traits class:

```
template<class T> struct TBootBootParams_traits;

template <class T>
struct TBootBootParams
{
    typename TBootBootParams_traits<T>::TransType transferType;

    typename TBootBootParams_traits<T>::UseAbort_ useAbort;

    bool GetImmediate()
    {
        if ( transferType == TBootBootParams_traits<T>::e1 )
        {
            return useAbort.someFlag;
        }

        return false;
    }

};

struct BootBootParams;
template<> struct TBootBootParams_traits<BootBootParams>
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        long long       someMember;             
        long long       otherMember;        
    };

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

struct BootBootParams : 
    public TBootBootParams<BootBootParams>, 
    public TBootBootParams_traits<BootBootParams>
{
    UseAbort_ useAbort;
};
```

Comment: This is a better hack than mine I think.  A bit cleaner.

Comment: Looks awesome. I just don't understand why `template<> struct TBootBootParams_traits` declaration doesn't have any type parameters within `<>` while its forward declaration does.

Comment: @Sergey: because it's a specialization. @All + @Omnifarious: It's a canonical way for passing some parameters to some template. E.g. STL uses it for iterators (iterator_traits).

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov - Because @ybungalobill is  declaring an explicit specialization of the TBootBootParams_traits class.  There would be one of these for each derived class.

Comment: @ybungalobill - Thats part of why I think it's cleaner.  It uses a pattern people are already familiar with.

Comment: This is realy great! I changed your solution a bit to look more gracefull. See code below

Answer (score 4):

There is no way this can work that isn't a bit of a hack.  So here is my attempt at a bit of a hack:

```
struct IBootParams
{
    virtual bool GetImmediate() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct TBootBootParams : public IBootParams
{
    typename T::TransType transferType;

    typename T::UseAbort_ useAbort;

    virtual bool GetImmediate()
    {
        if ( transferType == T::e1 )
        {
            return useAbort.someFlag;
        }

        return false;
    }

};

struct BootBootParams_types
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=0,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;

        char        someMember;
        int         otherMember;
    } useAbort;

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

struct BootBootParams : public BootBootParams_types,
                        public TBootBootParams<BootBootParams_types>
{
};

struct BootAltBootParams_types
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;

        long long       someMember;
        long long       otherMember;
    } useAbort;

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

struct BootAltBootParams : public BootAltBootParams_types,
                           public TBootBootParams<BootAltBootParams_types>
{
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    BootBootParams bp;
    BootAltBootParams bpa;

    bool f = bp.GetImmediate();
    f = bpa.GetImmediate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?  [It compiles.](http://ideone.com/RL7dV)

```
struct IBootParams
{
    virtual bool GetImmediate() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct TBootBootParams
{
    bool GetImmediate()
    {
        if ( static_cast<T*>(this)->transferType == T::e1 )
        {
            return static_cast<T*>(this)->useAbort.someFlag;
        }

        return false;
    }

};

struct BootBootParams : public TBootBootParams<BootBootParams> 
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=0,
        e2,
        e3
    } transferType;

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        char        someMember;             
        int         otherMember;        
    } useAbort;
};

struct BootAltBootParams : public TBootBootParams<BootAltBootParams> 
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    } transferType;

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        long long       someMember;             
        long long       otherMember;        
    } useAbort;
};

int main(void)
{
    BootBootParams bp;
    BootAltBootParams bpa;

    bool f = bp.GetImmediate();
    f = bpa.GetImmediate();
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I'm really impressed that compiles.  Is it supposed to compile?  Just because it actually works doesn't mean it's supposed to.  :-)

Comment: BTW, it also compiles on gcc 4.5.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Yes, this should compile, it's straightforward CRTP.  I got rid of the base class members that were causing the problem... since their data type is determined by the derived type, they can be declared in the derived type, and the base class can access them just fine by leveraging the template parameter.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Yep, it compiles. When you call member functions this way, it's called "static polymorphism". See [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: @Omnifarious, I think it compiles because it only refers to the types inside functions and functions are compiled after the class definition (otherwise they wouldn't be able to work with `this` properly as it would point to an incomplete type).

Comment: @ybungalobill: No derived-class member functions are being called.  I guess you meant "If you used this technique to call member functions, it would be called 'static polymorhpism'."?  But one of the advantages of CRTP/static polymorphism is that, unlike virtual functions, it also works for data, and doesn't require a particular signature, [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is possible.

Comment: @Sergey: That's right.  This "fix" wouldn't work if the base class member function return type depended on the derived class somehow, then the traits class as suggested by ybungalobill would be a good solution.

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid now.  I missed that the types were no longer being declared as member variables.

Comment: @Omnifarious: More precisely, they are member variables, but of the derived class which knows the correct type.

Comment: Wow. Thats great too! This not only solves the problem but prevents others from unappropriate use of the TBootBootParams (because static_cast would only be OK when T is a descendant of TBootBootParams). Simple and great!

Comment: @user369639: Most likely you will end up having to use both: type traits and use of `static_cast` to downcast to the template parameter.  Please note that `static_cast` WON'T generally prevent the programmer from doing something stupid, like a cast between unrelated types.  In order to make sure that the template is used properly, I like to put a line like this in the constructor or destructor: `TBootBootParams<T>* enforce_inheritance_relation = (T*)0;`  This will be eliminated by the optimizer, if `T` derives from `TBootBootParams<T>`, and a compile error if not.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a little change to ybungalobill's solution counting my own needs. And this what I got

```
template<class T> 
struct TBootBootParams_traits;

template <class T>
struct TBootBootParams
{
    typedef TBootBootParams_traits<T> Traits;

    typename Traits::TransType transferType;
    typename Traits::UseAbort_ useAbort;

    bool GetImmediate()
    {
        if ( transferType == TBootBootParams_traits<T>::e1 )
        {
            return useAbort.someFlag;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

struct BootBootParams;
struct BootAltBootParams;

template<> 
struct TBootBootParams_traits<BootBootParams>
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        long long       someMember;             
        long long       otherMember;        
    };

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

template<> 
struct TBootBootParams_traits<BootAltBootParams>
{
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        e1=5,
        e2,
        e3
    };

    struct UseAbort
    {
        bool        someFlag;           

        int someMember;             
        float otherMember;        
    };

    typedef SomeEnum TransType;
    typedef UseAbort UseAbort_;
};

struct BootBootParams : 
    public TBootBootParams<BootBootParams>
{

};

struct BootAltBootParams : 
    public TBootBootParams<BootAltBootParams>
{

};

int main(void)
{
    BootBootParams bp;
    BootAltBootParams bpa;

    bool f = bp.GetImmediate();
    f = bpa.GetImmediate();
}
```

To summarize.. I use a template class as a must-have option of another class for this class placing all type data there. This just what I needed. Thanks again for the option!

Answer (score 0):

For this approach to work, you have to include the template class object as a member of the parent class.